# How to override jQuery Validation Plugin messages with default broswer alert

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, alert

I am  running accross a situation here.

I have a form that fits in the design in such a way that I can't update de DOM inside the FORM to display validation messages.

So, I am wondering how I could replace custom jQuery Validation Plugin DOM messages with default browser alerts assuming the following code as example.

```
$("form").validate({
    rules:{
        myName:{
            required: true, minlength: 2
        },
        myEmail:{
            required: true, email: true
        },
        myMessage:{
            required: true, minlength: 10
        }
    },
    messages:{
        myName:{
            required: "Type you name",
            minLength: "Your name must be at least 2 characters long"
        },
        myEmail:{
            required: "Type you e-mail address",
            email: "Type a valid e-mail address"
        },
        myMessage:{
            required: "Type your message",
            minLength: Your message must be at least 2 characters long"
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "default browser alerts".

Answer (score 3):

- Your last custom message was missing the opening quotation mark, `"`.
- Your custom [`messages`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) should contain parameter placeholders, `{0}`, that are automatically replaced by the value of your rule.
- You also misspelled the `minlength` rule within the custom `messages` option by using a capital `L`.

Try this code instead:

```
$("form").validate({
    rules:{
        myName:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        myEmail:{
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        myMessage:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
        }
    },
    messages:{
        myName:{
            required: "Type your name",
            minlength: "Your name must be at least {0} characters long"
        },
        myEmail:{
            required: "Type your e-mail address",
            email: "Type a valid e-mail address"
        },
        myMessage:{
            required: "Type your message",
            minlength: "Your message must be at least {0} characters long"
        }
    }
});
```

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/3JTNh/**

---

> **Quote OP**:  "I am wondering how I could replace custom jQuery Validation Plugin DOM messages with default browser alerts"

<s>Your question is very unclear, but the way to dynamically change your messages would be to dynamically change your rules by using the [`rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules), and only specify the message(s) to change...  Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/vkF9r/</s>

`* removed *`

---

**EDIT**:

As per comments, the OP was originally asking for a JavaScript `alert()` which can be done using the `errorPlacement` callback function like this.  Since `error` is an object, you use `error.text()` to only use its message.

```
    onkeyup: false,
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        alert(error.text());
    },
```

I recommend setting `onkeyup` to `false` in order to negate a repeated alert on every keystroke.  **If you are using Safari, do not try this demo** or you'll get stuck in an infinite loop (one shortcoming of using `alert()` in this case) http://jsfiddle.net/kxwYd/

**BTW:  I do not recommend ever using the antiquated JavaScript `alert()` within any website design.**

---

**Better/Recommended**:

For a more modern user experience, you should instead integrate this with a jQuery modal or tooltip plugin like [Tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/).

**Working Example**:  http://jsfiddle.net/SfanE/

The following code is from [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235)...

First, initialize the Tooltipster plugin ([with any options](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#options)) on **all** specific `form` elements that will display errors:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // initialize tooltipster on form input elements
    $('#myform input[type="text"]').tooltipster({ 
        trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
        onlyOne: false, // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
        position: 'right'  // display the tips to the right of the element
    });

});
```

Second, use [Tooltipster's advanced options](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#advanced) along with the [`success:` and `errorPlacement:` callback functions built into the Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to automatically show and hide the tooltips as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // initialize validate plugin on the form
    $('#myform').validate({
        // any other options & rules,
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).data('tooltipsterContent', $(error).text());
            $(element).data('plugin_tooltipster').showTooltip();
        },
        success: function (label, element) {
            $(element).data('plugin_tooltipster').hideTooltip();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for the time you spent, and thank you for the tips. Howerver, the code is still not working the way it is needed.
When I mean "default browsers alert" I mean I don't want to append HTML to my page, I want an alert to be triggered alert('Message here'). It is ridiculous such a plugin being unable to trigger alerts without a flip flop option!

Comment: @GilbertoAlbino, that's because using `alert()`'s is no way to do a modern website with jQuery.  Use a jQuery tooltip or modal plugin instead.  See [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SfanE/) on this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235) for an example.

Comment: Yes, the tooltip idea was exactly what I was trying to do right now. Thanks for advancing that for me!

Comment: @GilbertoAlbino, I've updated my answer with both a way to use an `alert()` (not recommended) and the preferred way with a jQuery tooltip plugin.  Please accept my answer since it solved your question. Thanks.

Comment: thank you very much... but if using alert() I need to focus() the element after alert is closed... I will stay with tooltipster

Comment: @GilbertoAlbino, Yes , I agree... Tooltipster is the best way to go. However, as you can see by reading my answer, I've shown you how to do what you originally asked for **PLUS I also show you a better option with Tooltipster**, exactly like you want. You wouldn't have even known about how to use Tooltipster with this if not for my answer/comments/suggestions. There's no good reason not to click "accept" on this answer

Comment: @Sparky in errorPlacement Function alert Erorr message display only one at the submit time is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Building off what Sparky suggested, if you prefer not to include a tooltip plugin, you can emulate that behaviour pretty closely using jQuery UI and a bit of CSS.

CSS:

```
label.error {
    background-color:white;
    color:red;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888;
    z-index:1;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element).position({
            my: 'left center',
            at: 'right center',
            of: element,
            offset: '5 0'
        });

    },
   //the rest of your validate options
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SfanE/1/