# CSS form layout with jQuery Validation errors

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I have a form that I've styled with CSS to line up text boxes properly. I'm using [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) with the form. I'm running into a layout issue when I submit the form because of the errors that are being produced from the validation. My CSS is as follows:

```
#form p label {
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

I know the `float: left;` is causing the issue. I'm looking for the errors to appear next to each textbox without the layout changing. The class for jQuery Validation errors is `.errors`. I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5fR8/) to recreate my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS for the `label` elements is targeting **all** `label` elements on the page, so it's over-riding the `label` elements used by the plugin to display form errors.

Simply adding this CSS will set only the `label` elements used by the plugin *back to default values* without affecting any of your other `label` elements.

```
#form p label.error {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/4Wspp/**

---

**EDIT**:

My answer solves your question, but if you want to take more advantage of jQuery, you should check out another option using a jQuery plugin for fancy tool-tips.

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/kyK4G/

From this SO answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the plugin was using a label. This worked great.

Comment: @SeanWM, not a problem.  Also check out the edit on my answer for an alternative approach.

Comment: @if237912print, you are not supposed to ask new questions within comments.  Otherwise, this plugin's message placement has been solved many times here already; you simply need to search using the [tag:jquery-validate] tag and `errorPlacement`.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute positioning on your error element will allow your form to remain unchanged on an error. This will however require additional markup to maintain your form display. In this example, a wrapper of `<span class="item"></span>` was added to your input field to provide position boundaries for the error element.

Note that the properties set for the `label` element will affect your error label as well.

See http://jsfiddle.net/K5fR8/3/ for an example.

Full markup as follows:

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
<p>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <span class="item">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="" class="required" />
    </span>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <span class="item">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value="" class="required" />
    </span>
</p>
<p>
    <label for=""></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log In" class="button" />
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#form p label {
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#form p .item {
    position: relative;
}

#form p .item label.error {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100px; /* Offset by width set on label element */
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: @if237912print, please stop spamming comments with a question.  Post a question if you have a question.  Otherwise, message placement for this plugin has already been answered here numerous times.