# How do I get rid of this JS error: TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am using the following JS code from the fiddle provided in the answer here:

[How to display messages from jQuery Validate plugin inside of Tooltipster tooltips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741688/how-to-display-messages-from-jquery-validate-plugin-inside-of-tooltipster-toolti)

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyK4G/

The error shows up on line 36, which is: submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo

And this is the error:

```
TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
```

Code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    // initialize tooltipster on text input elements
    $('#myform input[type="text"]').tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom',
        onlyOne: false,
        position: 'right'
    });

    // initialize validate plugin on the form
    $('#myform').validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
            $(element).tooltipster('show');
        },
        success: function (label, element) {
            $(element).tooltipster('hide');
        },
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form');
            return false;
        }
    });

});

// no CDN - including plugin below
(function (d, f, g, b) {
    var e = "tooltipster",
        c = {
            animation: "fade",
            arrow: true,
            arrowColor: "",
            content: "",
            delay: 200,
            fixedWidth: 0,
            maxWidth: 0,
            functionBefore: function (l, m) {
                m()
            },
            functionReady: function (l, m) {},
            functionAfter: function (l) {},
            icon: "(?)",
            iconDesktop: false,
            iconTouch: false,
            iconTheme: ".tooltipster-icon",
            interactive: false,
            interactiveTolerance: 350,
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
            onlyOne: true,
            position: "top",
            speed: 350,
            timer: 0,
            theme: ".tooltipster-default",
            touchDevices: true,
            trigger: "hover"
        };

    function h(m, l) {
        this.element = m;
        this.options = d.extend({}, c, l);
        this._defaults = c;
        this._name = e;
        this.init()
    }
    function j() {
        return !!("ontouchstart" in f)
    }
    function a() {
        var l = g.body || g.documentElement;
        var n = l.style;
        var o = "transition";
        if (typeof n[o] == "string") {
            return true
        }
        v = ["Moz", "Webkit", "Khtml", "O", "ms"], o = o.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + o.substr(1);
        for (var m = 0; m < v.length; m++) {
            if (typeof n[v[m] + o] == "string") {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    var k = true;
    if (!a()) {
        k = false
    }
    h.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            var r = d(this.element);
            var n = this;
            var q = true;
            if ((n.options.touchDevices == false) && (j())) {
                q = false
            }
            if (g.all && !g.querySelector) {
                q = false
            }
            if (q == true) {
                if ((this.options.iconDesktop == true) && (!j()) || ((this.options.iconTouch == true) && (j()))) {
                    var m = r.attr("title");
                    r.removeAttr("title");
                    var p = n.options.iconTheme;
                    var o = d('<span class="' + p.replace(".", "") + '" title="' + m + '">' + this.options.icon + "</span>");
                    o.insertAfter(r);
                    r.data("tooltipsterIcon", o);
                    r = o
                }
                var l = d.trim(n.options.content).length > 0 ? n.options.content : r.attr("title");
                r.data("tooltipsterContent", l);
                r.removeAttr("title");
                if ((this.options.touchDevices == true) && (j())) {
                    r.bind("touchstart", function (t, s) {
                        n.showTooltip()
                    })
                } else {
                    if (this.options.trigger == "hover") {
                        r.on("mouseenter.tooltipster", function () {
                            n.showTooltip()
                        });
                        if (this.options.interactive == true) {
                            r.on("mouseleave.tooltipster", function () {
                                var t = r.data("tooltipster");
                                var u = false;
                                if ((t !== b) && (t !== "")) {
                                    t.mouseenter(function () {
                                        u = true
                                    });
                                    t.mouseleave(function () {
                                        u = false
                                    });
                                    var s = setTimeout(function () {
                                        if (u == true) {
                                            t.mouseleave(function () {
                                                n.hideTooltip()
                                            })
                                        } else {
                                            n.hideTooltip()
                                        }
                                    }, n.options.interactiveTolerance)
                                } else {
                                    n.hideTooltip()
                                }
                            })
                        } else {
                            r.on("mouseleave.tooltipster", function () {
                                n.hideTooltip()
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    if (this.options.trigger == "click") {
                        r.on("click.tooltipster", function () {
                            if ((r.data("tooltipster") == "") || (r.data("tooltipster") == b)) {
                                n.showTooltip()
                            } else {
                                n.hideTooltip()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        showTooltip: function (m) {
            var n = d(this.element);
            var l = this;
            if (n.data("tooltipsterIcon") !== b) {
                n = n.data("tooltipsterIcon")
            }
            if ((d(".tooltipster-base").not(".tooltipster-dying").length > 0) && (l.options.onlyOne == true)) {
                d(".tooltipster-base").not(".tooltipster-dying").not(n.data("tooltipster")).each(function () {
                    d(this).addClass("tooltipster-kill");
                    var o = d(this).data("origin");
                    o.data("plugin_tooltipster").hideTooltip()
                })
            }
            n.clearQueue().delay(l.options.delay).queue(function () {
                l.options.functionBefore(n, function () {
                    if ((n.data("tooltipster") !== b) && (n.data("tooltipster") !== "")) {
                        var w = n.data("tooltipster");
                        if (!w.hasClass("tooltipster-kill")) {
                            var s = "tooltipster-" + l.options.animation;
                            w.removeClass("tooltipster-dying");
                            if (k == true) {
                                w.clearQueue().addClass(s + "-show")
                            }
                            if (l.options.timer > 0) {
                                var q = w.data("tooltipsterTimer");
                                clearTimeout(q);
                                q = setTimeout(function () {
                                    w.data("tooltipsterTimer", b);
                                    l.hideTooltip()
                                }, l.options.timer);
                                w.data("tooltipsterTimer", q)
                            }
                            if ((l.options.touchDevices == true) && (j())) {
                                d("body").bind("touchstart", function (B) {
                                    if (l.options.interactive == true) {
                                        var D = d(B.target);
                                        var C = true;
                                        D.parents().each(function () {
                                            if (d(this).hasClass("tooltipster-base")) {
                                                C = false
                                            }
                                        });
                                        if (C == true) {
                                            l.hideTooltip();
                                            d("body").unbind("touchstart")
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        l.hideTooltip();
                                        d("body").unbind("touchstart")
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        d("body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
                        var x = n.data("tooltipsterContent");
                        var u = l.options.theme;
                        var y = u.replace(".", "");
                        var s = "tooltipster-" + l.options.animation;
                        var r = "-webkit-transition-duration: " + l.options.speed + "ms; -webkit-animation-duration: " + l.options.speed + "ms; -moz-transition-duration: " + l.options.speed + "ms; -moz-animation-duration: " + l.options.speed + "ms; -o-transition-duration: " + l.options.speed + "ms; -o-animation-duration: " + l.options.speed + "ms; -ms-transition-duration: " + l.options.speed + "ms; -ms-animation-duration: " + l.options.speed + "ms; transition-duration: " + l.options.speed + "ms; animation-duration: " + l.options.speed + "ms;";
                        var o = l.options.fixedWidth > 0 ? "width:" + l.options.fixedWidth + "px;" : "";
                        var z = l.options.maxWidth > 0 ? "max-width:" + l.options.maxWidth + "px;" : "";
                        var t = l.options.interactive == true ? "pointer-events: auto;" : "";
                        var w = d('<div class="tooltipster-base ' + y + " " + s + '" style="' + o + " " + z + " " + t + " " + r + '"><div class="tooltipster-content">' + x + "</div></div>");
                        w.appendTo("body");
                        n.data("tooltipster", w);
                        w.data("origin", n);
                        l.positionTooltip();
                        l.options.functionReady(n, w);
                        if (k == true) {
                            w.addClass(s + "-show")
                        } else {
                            w.css("display", "none").removeClass(s).fadeIn(l.options.speed)
                        }
                        var A = x;
                        var p = setInterval(function () {
                            var B = n.data("tooltipsterContent");
                            if (d("body").find(n).length == 0) {
                                w.addClass("tooltipster-dying");
                                l.hideTooltip()
                            } else {
                                if ((A !== B) && (B !== "")) {
                                    A = B;
                                    w.find(".tooltipster-content").html(B);
                                    w.css({
                                        width: "",
                                        "-webkit-transition-duration": l.options.speed + "ms",
                                        "-moz-transition-duration": l.options.speed + "ms",
                                        "-o-transition-duration": l.options.speed + "ms",
                                        "-ms-transition-duration": l.options.speed + "ms",
                                        "transition-duration": l.options.speed + "ms",
                                        "-webkit-transition-property": "-webkit-transform",
                                        "-moz-transition-property": "-moz-transform",
                                        "-o-transition-property": "-o-transform",
                                        "-ms-transition-property": "-ms-transform",
                                        "transition-property": "transform"
                                    }).addClass("tooltipster-content-changing");
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        w.removeClass("tooltipster-content-changing");
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                            w.css({
                                                "-webkit-transition-property": "",
                                                "-moz-transition-property": "",
                                                "-o-transition-property": "",
                                                "-ms-transition-property": "",
                                                "transition-property": ""
                                            })
                                        }, l.options.speed)
                                    }, l.options.speed);
                                    tooltipWidth = w.outerWidth(false);
                                    tooltipInnerWidth = w.innerWidth();
                                    tooltipHeight = w.outerHeight(false);
                                    l.positionTooltip()
                                }
                            }
                            if ((d("body").find(w).length == 0) || (d("body").find(n).length == 0)) {
                                clearInterval(p)
                            }
                        }, 200);
                        if (l.options.timer > 0) {
                            var q = setTimeout(function () {
                                w.data("tooltipsterTimer", b);
                                l.hideTooltip()
                            }, l.options.timer + l.options.speed);
                            w.data("tooltipsterTimer", q)
                        }
                        if ((l.options.touchDevices == true) && (j())) {
                            d("body").bind("touchstart", function (B) {
                                if (l.options.interactive == true) {
                                    var D = d(B.target);
                                    var C = true;
                                    D.parents().each(function () {
                                        if (d(this).hasClass("tooltipster-base")) {
                                            C = false
                                        }
                                    });
                                    if (C == true) {
                                        l.hideTooltip();
                                        d("body").unbind("touchstart")
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    l.hideTooltip();
                                    d("body").unbind("touchstart")
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        w.mouseleave(function () {
                            l.hideTooltip()
                        })
                    }
                });
                n.dequeue()
            })
        },
        hideTooltip: function (m) {
            var p = d(this.element);
            var l = this;
            if (p.data("tooltipsterIcon") !== b) {
                p = p.data("tooltipsterIcon")
            }
            var o = p.data("tooltipster");
            if (o == b) {
                o = d(".tooltipster-dying")
            }
            p.clearQueue();
            if ((o !== b) && (o !== "")) {
                var q = o.data("tooltipsterTimer");
                if (q !== b) {
                    clearTimeout(q)
                }
                var n = "tooltipster-" + l.options.animation;
                if (k == true) {
                    o.clearQueue().removeClass(n + "-show").addClass("tooltipster-dying").delay(l.options.speed).queue(function () {
                        o.remove();
                        p.data("tooltipster", "");
                        d("body").css("verflow-x", "");
                        l.options.functionAfter(p)
                    })
                } else {
                    o.clearQueue().addClass("tooltipster-dying").fadeOut(l.options.speed, function () {
                        o.remove();
                        p.data("tooltipster", "");
                        d("body").css("verflow-x", "");
                        l.options.functionAfter(p)
                    })
                }
            }
        },
        positionTooltip: function (O) {
            var A = d(this.element);
            var ab = this;
            if (A.data("tooltipsterIcon") !== b) {
                A = A.data("tooltipsterIcon")
            }
            if ((A.data("tooltipster") !== b) && (A.data("tooltipster") !== "")) {
                var ah = A.data("tooltipster");
                ah.css("width", "");
                var ai = d(f).width();
                var B = A.outerWidth(false);
                var ag = A.outerHeight(false);
                var al = ah.outerWidth(false);
                var m = ah.innerWidth() + 1;
                var M = ah.outerHeight(false);
                var aa = A.offset();
                var Z = aa.top;
                var u = aa.left;
                var y = b;
                if (A.is("area")) {
                    var T = A.attr("shape");
                    var af = A.parent().attr("name");
                    var P = d('img[usemap="#' + af + '"]');
                    var n = P.offset().left;
                    var L = P.offset().top;
                    var W = A.attr("coords") !== b ? A.attr("coords").split(",") : b;
                    if (T == "circle") {
                        var N = parseInt(W[0]);
                        var r = parseInt(W[1]);
                        var D = parseInt(W[2]);
                        ag = D * 2;
                        B = D * 2;
                        Z = L + r - D;
                        u = n + N - D
                    } else {
                        if (T == "rect") {
                            var N = parseInt(W[0]);
                            var r = parseInt(W[1]);
                            var q = parseInt(W[2]);
                            var J = parseInt(W[3]);
                            ag = J - r;
                            B = q - N;
                            Z = L + r;
                            u = n + N
                        } else {
                            if (T == "poly") {
                                var x = [];
                                var ae = [];
                                var H = 0,
                                    G = 0,
                                    ad = 0,
                                    ac = 0;
                                var aj = "even";
                                for (i = 0; i < W.length; i++) {
                                    var F = parseInt(W[i]);
                                    if (aj == "even") {
                                        if (F > ad) {
                                            ad = F;
                                            if (i == 0) {
                                                H = ad
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (F < H) {
                                            H = F
                                        }
                                        aj = "odd"
                                    } else {
                                        if (F > ac) {
                                            ac = F;
                                            if (i == 1) {
                                                G = ac
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (F < G) {
                                            G = F
                                        }
                                        aj = "even"
                                    }
                                }
                                ag = ac - G;
                                B = ad - H;
                                Z = L + G;
                                u = n + H
                            } else {
                                ag = P.outerHeight(false);
                                B = P.outerWidth(false);
                                Z = L;
                                u = n
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (ab.options.fixedWidth == 0) {
                    ah.css({
                        width: m + "px",
                        "padding-left": "0px",
                        "padding-right": "0px"
                    })
                }
                var s = 0,
                    V = 0;
                var X = parseInt(ab.options.offsetY);
                var Y = parseInt(ab.options.offsetX);
                var p = "";

                function w() {
                    var an = d(f).scrollLeft();
                    if ((s - an) < 0) {
                        var am = s - an;
                        s = an;
                        ah.data("arrow-reposition", am)
                    }
                    if (((s + al) - an) > ai) {
                        var am = s - ((ai + an) - al);
                        s = (ai + an) - al;
                        ah.data("arrow-reposition", am)
                    }
                }
                function t(an, am) {
                    if (((Z - d(f).scrollTop() - M - X - 12) < 0) && (am.indexOf("top") > -1)) {
                        ab.options.position = an;
                        y = am
                    }
                    if (((Z + ag + M + 12 + X) > (d(f).scrollTop() + d(f).height())) && (am.indexOf("bottom") > -1)) {
                        ab.options.position = an;
                        y = am;
                        V = (Z - M) - X - 12
                    }
                }
                if (ab.options.position == "top") {
                    var Q = (u + al) - (u + B);
                    s = (u + Y) - (Q / 2);
                    V = (Z - M) - X - 12;
                    w();
                    t("bottom", "top")
                }
                if (ab.options.position == "top-left") {
                    s = u + Y;
                    V = (Z - M) - X - 12;
                    w();
                    t("bottom-left", "top-left")
                }
                if (ab.options.position == "top-right") {
                    s = (u + B + Y) - al;
                    V = (Z - M) - X - 12;
                    w();
                    t("bottom-right", "top-right")
                }
                if (ab.options.position == "bottom") {
                    var Q = (u + al) - (u + B);
                    s = u - (Q / 2) + Y;
                    V = (Z + ag) + X + 12;
                    w();
                    t("top", "bottom")
                }
                if (ab.options.position == "bottom-left") {
                    s = u + Y;
                    V = (Z + ag) + X + 12;
                    w();
                    t("top-left", "bottom-left")
                }
                if (ab.options.position == "bottom-right") {
                    s = (u + B + Y) - al;
                    V = (Z + ag) + X + 12;
                    w();
                    t("top-right", "bottom-right")
                }
                if (ab.options.position == "left") {
                    s = u - Y - al - 12;
                    myLeftMirror = u + Y + B + 12;
                    var K = (Z + M) - (Z + A.outerHeight(false));
                    V = Z - (K / 2) - X;
                    if ((s < 0) && ((myLeftMirror + al) > ai)) {
                        var o = parseFloat(ah.css("border-width")) * 2;
                        var l = (al + s) - o;
                        ah.css("width", l + "px");
                        M = ah.outerHeight(false);
                        s = u - Y - l - 12 - o;
                        K = (Z + M) - (Z + A.outerHeight(false));
                        V = Z - (K / 2) - X
                    } else {
                        if (s < 0) {
                            s = u + Y + B + 12;
                            ah.data("arrow-reposition", "left")
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (ab.options.position == "right") {
                    s = u + Y + B + 12;
                    myLeftMirror = u - Y - al - 12;
                    var K = (Z + M) - (Z + A.outerHeight(false));
                    V = Z - (K / 2) - X;
                    if (((s + al) > ai) && (myLeftMirror < 0)) {
                        var o = parseFloat(ah.css("border-width")) * 2;
                        var l = (ai - s) - o;
                        ah.css("width", l + "px");
                        M = ah.outerHeight(false);
                        K = (Z + M) - (Z + A.outerHeight(false));
                        V = Z - (K / 2) - X
                    } else {
                        if ((s + al) > ai) {
                            s = u - Y - al - 12;
                            ah.data("arrow-reposition", "right")
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (ab.options.arrow == true) {
                    var I = "tooltipster-arrow-" + ab.options.position;
                    if (ab.options.arrowColor.length < 1) {
                        var R = ah.css("background-color")
                    } else {
                        var R = ab.options.arrowColor
                    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the validate plugin script on the page:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are not including the jQuery plugin that provides the `.validate()` method. You should include it after jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"><script>
```

Generally, if you have an object, you can try and access different attributes using dot notation as follows:

```
var myAwesomeObject = {
    coolProperty: "whooooa!"
  , coolMethod: function() {return this;}
};

myAwesomeObject.coolProperty; // "whooooa!"
myAwesomeObject.coolMethod; // function(){return this;}
```

If the property happens to be a method, you can call it like:

```
myAwesomeObject.coolMethod(); // Object {coolProperty: ...
```

If the property you are trying to access doesn't exist on  the object, you will get back `undefined`

```
myAwesomeObject.missingProperty; // undefined
```

Since `undefined` is not a function, trying to call a missing property as a method will result in the error you saw:

```
myAwesomeObject.missingMethod(); // TypeError: you messed up.
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to this so a bit confused.  What exactly do I need to include under JQuery.  I have the following link and then under that I have my code:  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @starbucks see update for a snippet to include jQuery.validate

Comment: Using the js I have up there, how can i modify it so that besides showing a tooltip for missed field it also highlights the input field?  Thanks!

Comment: @starbucks that should probably be a separate question

Comment: will you be able to help me if i post it as a separate question?

Comment: @starbucks in your `errorPlacement` function, add something like: `$(element).css('border', '1px solid red');` and make sure to remove the style once the field has valid input. If you want to go into more depth, please ask in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem. I have fixed this problem other way. That I got in [the documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#content-types)

To fix the problem you have to declared a specific class.
Using the

`mfp-TYPE` CSS class (where TYPE is the desired content type). For example: `<a class="mfp-image image-link">Open image</a>, $('.image-link').magnificPopup().`

Another Example: `<a class="mfp-iframe video-link">Open Video</a>, $('.video-link').magnificPopup().`