# Multiple rules with jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following form:

```
<form id="fromWiw" action="..." method="post">                    
  ...
  <div class="controls span5 pull-left">
      <label class="control-label" for="Quantity">@Resources.Quantity</label>
      <input class="span12" id="Quantity" name="Quantity" type="number" min="0" value="0" required />
  </div>
  <div class="controls span5 pull-left">
      <label class="control-label" for="Price">@Resources.Price</label>
      <input class="span12" id="Price" name="Price" required />
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

For the validation part, I have this code snippet:

```
form.submit(function() {
    form.validate(
        {
            rules: {
                Quantity: { required: true, number: true},
                Price: { required: true, number: true }
            }
        });
});
```

**PROBLEM**
The validation is working fine, it is detecting when the price and quantity are empty. However, the validation successfully passes when the price input contains non numeric values, text for example. The validation works fine for the Quantity input. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
form.submit(function() {
    form.validate({
        ...
    })
})
```

> *"The validation works fine for the Quantity input. Am I doing something wrong here?"*

Yes, you are.

`.validate()` is only the *initialization* method of the plugin on your form... it's not the testing method, and therefore does not belong inside of a `submit` handler.  It should be called *once* on DOM ready instead.  The plugin will automatically capture the `submit` event just fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        // rules & options
    });

});
```

You are also mixing HTML5 validation along with the Validation plugin.

There is no need to put the `required` attribute inside the HTML as well as declaring `required` within `.validate()`.  The plugin will pick it up from either method; and when the plugin is used, it dynamically adds a `novalidate="novalidate"` attribute into the `<form>` tag to disable any HTML5 validation.

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/bNGQP/

Comment: Yep it works fine. but now instead of having popovers I get inline error messages on my form. Any hints as to how the get the popovers back?

Comment: @GETah, the popovers are generated by HTML5 in your browser... they have nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Remove the plugin and you'll see.  When using jQuery Validate, HTML5 validation is automatically disabled.  See my edits.

Comment: @GETah, if you want popovers with jQuery Validate, try Tooltipster.  See the jsFiddle demos in this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235