# can't get jquery highlight to work on form validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, popover

I am new here and would like a little help if possible. I have a form that I am validating but would like to also highlight the error fields as well as keep the popover. I can't work out what is wrong?

It is on jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/mKF5L/75/

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        subject: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10

        },
        comment: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 200
        }

    },

    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },

    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

        $.each(this.successList, function (index, value) {
            $(value).popover('hide');
        });


        $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {

            console.log(value.message);

            var _popover = $(value.element).popover({
                trigger: 'manual',
                placement: 'top',
                content: value.message,
                template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
            });

            _popover.data('bs.popover').options.content = value.message;

            $(value.element).popover('show');

        });
    }
});
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks in advance

Gary.

Comment: Firstly, you're including jQuery twice and jQuery Validate plugin twice in your jsFiddle.  You don't need both the `minified` and `unminified` versions.

Comment: Secondly, `showErrors` is not for placing individual errors within popovers, it's for an error summary control.  If you want to place individual errors, use the `errorPlacement` callback.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235) and [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyK4G/) for a working example using the Tooltipster plugin.  Even though you're using a different tooltip mechanism, the concept is the same.

Comment: @Sparky, Thank you very much. After looking at and using the example you provided I now at least have a form that validates and highlights as I want. Thank you very much for the pointers. I have also updated the jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/mKF5L/111/ , to reflect my new form setup. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `showErrors` callback is not for placing individual errors, it's for creating error summaries.

So you'd need to use the `errorPlacement` and `success` callback functions to control your tooltips.

Here is a similar setup using the Tooltipster plugin, just to give you an idea.  Adjust as needed...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
            // rules and options here,
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
                $(element).tooltipster('show');
            },
            success: function (label, element) {
                $(element).tooltipster('hide');
            }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/kyK4G/**

**Reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235**

**Documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate**