# Integrate jquery.validate with bootstrap popover

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I've a registration form validated with jquery.validate plugin.

Now, if the form its not valid, i want to put the result of validate in a bootstrap popover, but really, i don't have idea how i can do this.

Some help?

Comment: Search SO for code examples using the `errorPlacement` callback.   Make an attempt to solve this yourself, then show your attempt when asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this: https://github.com/mingliangfeng/jquery.validate.bootstrap.popover

it is a plugin integrating jQuery validate and bootstrap popover, you may get some idea there.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery.validate plugin has a method called `errorPlacement`.

This takes 2 arguments:

- **error**: the error message created by the validator on that element.
- **element**: the element being validated.

The Validator sends the error/valid message here and you can handle all the placement logic in there. What I tend to do is put all that in `.setDefaults` before initialising the validator.

Example:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
   ignore: "",
   errorPlacement: function (error, element){
       // Insert error messgae placement logic here
   }
});
```

Comment: Unless you are using `unobtrusive.validate` or have multiple forms, I don't see the advantage of using `setDefaults()`.  Why not show the OP a plain vanilla initialization using `.validate()`?

Comment: `setDefaults()` reduces repetition of code. Having one location with the default settings allows multiple instances of `validate()` to be created without the need to define `errorPlacement` each time.

Comment: That's why I said, _"Unless you ... have multiple forms,..."_.  However, typically, I don't believe this to be the case, and you should have shown a plain example to reduce confusion.  Also, including the `ignore` option without relevant context is not helpful.  In this case, `ignore` has nothing to do with anything the OP has asked.

Comment: 1. OP may not be aware of the `setDefaults()` option, so explaining it will increase his knowledge of the plugin. 2. The example was mainly to give an overview of what properties can be included within `setDefaults()`. If the OP was confused I'm sure he can comment so I can clear anything up for him.

Comment: No reason to get defensive... FWIW, my comments were only meant as helpful suggestions for turning a plain answer into something worthy of many up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

For showing and hiding tooltips for your errors, you'd need to use the `errorPlacement` and `success` callback functions.

Since you've shown no code of your own, here is a similar setup using the Tooltipster plugin, just to give you an idea about how to use these callback functions.  Adjust as needed for Bootstrap popovers or whatever other  tooltip plugin you may use.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
            // rules and options here,
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                // construct tooltip with message as per plugin method
                $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());  
                // show tooltip as per plugin method
                $(element).tooltipster('show');
            },
            success: function (label, element) {
                // hide tooltip as per plugin method
                $(element).tooltipster('hide');
            }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/kyK4G/**

**Reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235**

**Documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate**