# Bootstrap 3 validation states with JQuery-validated form that uses Chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

**The context**

- I have a form that I'm validating using [JQuery Validate Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).
- All form controls are required except for the textarea.
- I'm using Bootstrap 3 validation states to style the form controls being validated.
- For the select control, I'm using the [Chosen Select Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

**The problem**

I'm having trouble figuring out how to address the following:

1- Prevent the textarea control from being applied the success validation state since this form control is not being validated as it is optional.

(To reproduce the problem in the JSFiddle below, click the Submit button with the empty form)

2- Apply the error validation state to the border of the dropdown list. Right now only the label gets the error validation state applied.

3 - Remove the error validation state and error message, and apply the success class when the user chooses an option from the dropdown list. Right now the error message and error class remain.

**A JSFiddle**

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxvqsodz/3/) to illustrate the problems.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="container" role="main">
    <!-- Contents of the popover associated with the task name text input -->
    <div id="namePopoverContent" class="hide">
        <ul>
            <li><small>...</small></li>
            <li><small>...</small></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" id="taskForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="taskName" class="control-label col-md-1">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control taskNameValidation" id="taskName" name="taskName" autofocus required data-toggle="popover">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="taskDataset" class="col-md-1 control-label">Dataset</label>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <select class="form-control chosen-select taskDatasetValidation" data-placeholder="Choose a dataset" name="taskDataset" id="taskDataset" required>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="runnableDataset_Id1">Dataset 1</option>
                            <option value="runnableDataset_Id2">Dataset 2</option>
                            <option value="runnableDataset_Id3">Dataset 3</option>
                            <option value="runnableDataset_Id4">Dataset 4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="taskDescription" class="col-md-1 control-label">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="taskDescription" id="taskDescription" maxlength="1000" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="pull-right top-margin">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Submit" name="taskSetUpSubmit">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**The JS**

```
//Bootstrap popover
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ 
    trigger: "hover focus",
    container: "body",
    placement: "bottom",
    html: true,
    title: "Name Tips",
    content: function() { return $('#namePopoverContent').html();}
});

//Chosen select plugin
$(function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
    $('.chosen-select-deselect').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
});

//JQuery validate plugin
$(function() {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorClass: 'text-danger',
        ignore: ':hidden:not(.chosen-select)',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.hasClass('chosen-select'))
                error.insertAfter(element.siblings(".chosen-container"));
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });

    //rules and messages objects
    $("#taskForm").validate({
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        }
    });

    $('.taskNameValidation').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Provide a space-separated name"
            }
        });
    });

    $('.taskDatasetValidation').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Choose a dataset"
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I've been struggling with this without any luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > Prevent the textarea control from being applied the success validation state since this form control is not being validated as it is optional.

   The empty `textarea` is "valid" because your validation says an empty field is valid, therefore it's green.   You could *conditionally* use `highlight` and `unhighlight` so that it will not be applied to your `textarea`.  However, then it will not work when your `maxlength` rule is evaluated.  <s>I know of no workaround that will cause `unhighlight` to get ignored when the field is technically "valid" and yet still empty.</s>  There is no "optional" condition/state provided in this plugin... once the form is evaluated, fields are either "valid" or "invalid", nothing in between.

   **EDIT**:  You can conditionally apply `highlight` and `unhighlight` on the `textarea` using the custom `:blank` selector and applying a class to this "optional" element.  Then you'll still get the red & green outlines, but only when this "optional" field is filled out and/or your rules are evaluated.

   ```
   highlight: function (element) {
       if (! ($(element).hasClass('optional') && $(element).is(':blank'))) {
           $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
       }
   },
   unhighlight: function (element) {
       if (! ($(element).hasClass('optional') && $(element).is(':blank'))) {
           $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
       }
   }
   ```
2. > Apply the error validation state to the border of the dropdown list. Right now only the label gets the error validation state applied.

   You need to look at the rendered DOM and find the dynamically created Chosen element.  Then you need to write jQuery to traverse over to this element and conditionally apply the appropriate classes via `highlight` and `unhighlight`.

   ```
   highlight: function (element) {
       if ($(element).hasClass('chosen-select')) {
           $(element).siblings('.chosen-container').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
       }
       $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
   },
   unhighlight: function (element) {
      if ($(element).hasClass('chosen-select')) {
          $(element).siblings('.chosen-container').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
      } 
      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
   }
   ```

   This code above **is** applying the `has-error` and `has-success` classes to the rendered Chosen `div` element; you just need to adjust your CSS so that there is a red border.  Otherwise, write your own CSS classes for this like I did in the demo below.  Adjust accordingly.
3. > Remove the error validation state and error message, and apply the success class when the user chooses an option from the dropdown list.

   You must write a `change` handler that calls the `.valid()` method on the `select` element every time it changes.  This is because you are interacting with the rendered select list and not the actual `select` element.  Otherwise, the jQuery Validate plugin is not properly triggered.

   ```
   $('.chosen-select').on('change', function () {
       $(this).valid();
   });
   ```

**DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/jxvqsodz/7/**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm new to all web development technologies, so I really appreciate your detailed explanation.

Comment: @user2669241, you're welcome.  Thank-you for taking the time to properly write your question.

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but I'll ask it anyway. You said "You need to look at the rendered DOM and find the dynamically created Chosen element,"which makes sense, but how can I do that? When debugging back then, I looked at the page source, but I could only see what I could see in my code: the statically created controls. I guess my question is how to debug dynamically created elements. Thanks!

Comment: @user2669241:   I cannot be more specific because all browsers  have different tools and GUI.  However, within your browser's developer tools, there is an option to inspect the DOM, rather than the source.