# jquery validation with tooltipster error message placement issue for multiple checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, tooltipster

I'm using jquery validate with the tooltipster to show the error messages as tooltips instead of default. The issue I'm having is the error message placement for multiple checkboxes. I want to show on the main label(which is Location in this case) instead of showing on the first checkbox. Below is the sample code,

Form:

```
<form id="myform">
    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <br/>
    <label for="telf_local">In state</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="telf" name="telf" value="1" />
    <label for="telf_movil">Out of state</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="telf" name="telf" value="2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // initialize tooltipster on text input elements
    $('#myform :input').tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom',
        onlyOne: false,
        position: 'right'
    });

    // initialize validate plugin on the form
    $('#myform').validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

            var lastError = $(element).data('lastError'),
                newError = $(error).text();

            $(element).data('lastError', newError);

            if (newError !== '' && newError !== lastError) {
                $(element).tooltipster('content', newError);
                $(element).tooltipster('show');
            }

        },
        success: function (label, element) {
            $(element).tooltipster('hide');
        },
        rules: {
            telf: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue I'm having is the error message placement for multiple checkboxes.

You're configuring/initializing ToolTipster for all `input` elements at once...

```
$('#myform :input').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    onlyOne: false,
    position: 'right'  // <- same position for everything
});
```

Instead, configure/initialize ToolTipster for each `input` element `type`.  Then you can set custom placement options for the checkbox tooltips.

```
// text inputs
$('#myform input[type="text"]').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    onlyOne: false,
    position: 'right'
});

// checkbox inputs
$('#myform input[type="checkbox"]').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    onlyOne: false,
    // your custom positioning options here
});
```

See the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21027100/594235).