# CSS pseudo-elements not working with my label elements

Tags: html, css, jquery-validate, label, pseudo-element

Trying to style the error output on jquery.validate and I am not getting any success using Pseudo-elements in the css. Anyone ever have any success styling an error box with an arrow on the top with jquery.validate? Can get the box with the with arrow on top using normal CSS but not with jquery.validate?.

Used http://cssarrowplease.com/ to get the CSS (code below). Thanks

```
<style type="text/css">
label.error {
    float: none;
    color: red;
    padding: .8em;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:12px;
    display: inline;
    font-style:normal;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
label.error:after, label.error:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 30%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

label.error:after {
    border-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
label.error:before {
    border-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #ccc;
    border-width: 9px;
    margin-left: -9px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This question has nearly nothing to do with jQuery Validate and everything to do with CSS styling of a `label` element.  Retagging.  It would also help everyone if you could show the rendered DOM markup of the `label` element.  In other words, you have to do a much better job constructing your example code.

Comment: **Quote OP**:  _"Used [http://cssarrowplease.com/](http://cssarrowplease.com/) to get the CSS (code below)"_  ~  then why are the CSS rules in your OP **not** the same as provided at that link?

Comment: Since, by your own admission, you're not an expert in CSS, why reinvent the wheel?  You can easily combine jQuery Validate with the Tooltipster plugin where all the difficult CSS tooltips are provided for you.  See this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741688/how-to-display-messages-from-jquery-validate-plugin-inside-of-tooltipster-toolti) and this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2DUX2/3/).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is failing is because your trying to apply it to a `<label>` element.

The [code you've linked to](http://cssarrowplease.com/) is applying the sample CSS to a `<div>` element, which is nothing like a `<label>`.

Use [the `errorElement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) to force the jQuery Validate plugin to use `<div>` elements instead of `label`.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // your other options, rules, and callbacks
    errorElement: 'div'
});
```

Don't forget to change `label.error` into `div.error` in all of your CSS rules.

You're going to need the specificity of `div.error` because the plugin also applies the `error` class to the input elements.

---

**EDIT:**

Since, by your own admission, you're *"not an expert in CSS"*, why reinvent the wheel?  You can easily combine jQuery Validate with a tooltip plugin, like Tooltipster, where all the difficult CSS tooltips are provided for you.  See this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741688/how-to-display-messages-from-jquery-validate-plugin-inside-of-tooltipster-toolti) and this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2DUX2/3/).

Comment: I am using the standard CSS for error formatting that I found in several places. http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/Demos/#AdaptingCSS

Comment: @user1324471, Based on your OP, you're using the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidate.com), which has absolutely nothing to do with [the Validity plugin](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/).  Also, until you realize the differences between a `<label>` element and a `<div>` element and how to properly apply CSS to each, nobody is going to be able to help.  It just seems like you're confusing a bunch of different code examples without any fundamental understanding.  Sorry.

Comment: plenty of opinions regarding my lack of knowledge without any solutions. I have been using jquery validate for several years and have always relied on the standard label element in css to style the error output. As I am not an expert in jquery or CSS I do know one thing to be true, it has worked for me on numerous production sites. I was simply trying to get a bubble with an arrow to display the error.

Comment: @user1324471, Perhaps you just want me to do all the work for you?  I don't know how many times/ways I can explain it.  You cannot take CSS meant for a `div` and simply attach it to a `label`.  The CSS you've shown in your OP is also not the same as provided in [the example you've linked to](http://cssarrowplease.com/).

Comment: **Quote @user1324471:** _"...it has worked for me on numerous production sites"_ ~ then why are you here asking for help?  I've explained where you're going wrong and how to get around it, but you simply reject it without even trying.  (I've since edited my answer with an alternative solution that doesn't require you to write any CSS.)