# jQuery Validation - How to display the default callout on errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

If I create an input control like this:

```
<input type="number">
```

And type letters in it, an error will be displayed in a popup-like control. I've seen it referred to as a *callout* but I'm not sure if that's the right name. It looks like this:

[image]

But if I define my own rules in either the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) or in ASP.NET then there's no fancy popup anymore, just a label which is appended. It doesn't look nearly as good and it isn't very consistent with the above either.

Is there a simple way to make my custom error messages show up in the same way?

Comment: That 'callout' as you refer to it is actually chromes way of interpreting the spec, the error message will look different or not pop up at all in some browsers *stares at IE*

Comment: Interesting, I just tested on Firefox and you're right! Would you mind posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your picture shows the default HTML5 validation which is rendered (*or not rendered*) depending solely on the specific browser version.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGi5z.jpg]

The browser **must** support HTML5 validation in order to see these pop-ups and Chrome's pop-ups will look different than Firefox's, etc.  HTML5 validation is configured using [HTML5 validation attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML) that you'd add *inline* to each `input` element like this...

```
<input type="number" required="required" max="5" ....
```

---

However, when you employ [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org), it dynamically adds the `novalidate` attribute to the `<form>` tag...

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" id="myform" ....
```

The `novalidate` attribute is used to *disable* the HTML5 validation so that jQuery Validate can take over all form validation without interference from HTML5.  Yes, the default jQuery Validate labels are bland, but that's the "blank canvas" which allows design flexibility and cross-browser consistency and reliability.  See below.

---

If you want error messages that look more like the pop-ups you'd get with HTML5, then you can create your own with CSS/jQuery.

**Quote:**

> *"Is there a simple way to make my custom error messages show up in the same way?"*

That depends on if you think adding another jQuery plugin is simple.  You could integrate a jQuery plugin like [qTip2](http://qtip2.com) or [ToolTipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) into jQuery Validate.  These plugins have many options, themes, and CSS that you can customize to no end.  It can be tricky though as each plugin gets integrated differently depending on how it works, its manipulation methods, callbacks, etc.

Here's a working demo showing how ToolTipster v3 (default - no theme) was easily integrated into jQuery Validate:

http://jsfiddle.net/2DUX2/3/

[image]

**Source**:  [How to display messages from jQuery Validate plugin inside of Tooltipster tooltips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741688/how-to-display-messages-from-jquery-validate-plugin-inside-of-tooltipster-toolti)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are talking is HTML5 feature use `required` attribute with your form element

```
<input required>
```

and it will show you default error message but if you want to show custom error message than use `title` attribute

```
<input required title="Custom error message">
```

Check this URL for more information http://demosthenes.info/blog/848/Create-Custom-HTML5-Form-Error-Messages-with-the-Title-Attribute

Hope it will answer your question

Comment: That wouldn't come up if I type letters in a numeric textbox. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Check the link which I added

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate your effort. But that's still not what I was asking for. I was asking how to achieve the popup-like (or callout if you will) effect instead of a text message.

Comment: can you put some picture for example

Answer (score 1):

That 'callout' as you refer to it is actually chromes way of interpreting the spec, the error message will look different or not pop up at all in some browsers

*stares at IE*

Comment: I see some downvotes on this answer guys, please leave a comment explaining why you think it is bad.  Bearing in mind it is just a simplified version of the answer marked correct