# jQuery Validation and Tipsy not working with select in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, tipsy

I use jQuery Validation plugin for validate my form and use Tipsy tooltip for error messages. I have a problem to work for drop-down in IE 10/11.

After validation, if the field reports a required message the drop-down opens and closes automatically without giving you the opportunity to select the field.

```
    $('[id^="form-"] :input').tipsy({
       trigger: 'manual',
       fade: true,
       gravity: 'e',
       className: 'tip-blue'
    });


    $("#form-account").validate({ 
    ...
    errorPlacement: function (error, element)
    {
        element.attr('title', error.text());
        element.tipsy('show');
    },
```

How can I fix it?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s1jd5syr/)

Comment: Integrating a jQuery tooltip plugin with the jQuery Validate plugin can be a very complex task that depends on the methods made available by both plugins.  So you're going to have to put a lot more effort into writing your question... like including a more complete demo along with the relevant HTML and the rest of what's inside your `.validate()` method.  Meanwhile, [take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235) to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Since jQuery is designed to normalize these behaviors to work in all browsers including IE 10/11, you're really going to have to examine your HTML structure.  I suspect that you have invalid HTML that Explorer cannot handle.

Comment: @Sparky - The html code not report errors (with firebug and IE console). I read a post where someone said that "It looks like IE does not like the title attribute on selects".

Comment: @Sparky - I add a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: You need to use [the W3 HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org), not the console for that.

Comment: There is nothing in the spec that says you cannot have a `title` on `select` elements.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: @Sparky _ If you try my demo with IE11 can see the problem. It unfortunately does not depend html code wrong :( . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *the field reports a required message*

This whole problem has to do with how IE is triggering the events whenever you make a selection.  In other browsers, simply selecting a new option immediately triggers re-validation.  However, in Explorer, the re-validation is not triggered until you focus completely out of the `select` field.

The workaround is to manually capture the `change` event and force re-validation by using the plugin's `.valid()` method.

```
$('[name="user"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/d7apuegL/**

---

**Quote OP**:

> *the drop-down opens and closes automatically*

This is because IE is re-rendering the activated `select` element every-time you change its `title` attribute; and your `errorPlacement` function is changing the `title` whenever you try to make a selection.

It's not perfect, but the only workaround seems to be moving the custom error message into the `title` attribute of the `select`.

HTML:

```
<select name="user" id="test" title="error">
```

jQuery:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    // element.attr('title', error.text()); // remove this
    element.tipsy('show');
},
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/d7apuegL/1/**

---

As long as your solution depends upon dynamically changing the `title` attribute while the `select` is activated, you're always going to have some form of this issue.  It's just how IE works, so it might be best to totally break your dependency upon the `title` attribute or use a different tooltip plugin entirely.

See:  [How to display messages from jQuery Validate plugin inside of Tooltipster tooltips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741688/how-to-display-messages-from-jquery-validate-plugin-inside-of-tooltipster-toolti/14741689#14741689)

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2012j6dv/**

Comment: The second option seemed to solve my problem, but I realized that after I selected the field and try to select it again the problem (close automatically) still occurs .. thanks for your help!

Comment: @PaoloRossi, I said it wasn't perfect and as long as you're dependent upon changing the `title` attribute while the select is activated, you're always going to have some form of this issue.  If it were mine, I'd totally break the dependency upon the `title` attribute and use a different tooltip plugin if necessary.

Comment: thank you very much for your help and the time you have dedicated to my problem. I would like to ask you if you know a tooltip plugin that allows me to solve this problem. Thanks again

Comment: @PaoloRossi, I'd edited my question to refer to a solution you can use immediately.