# How to properly integrate tooltips with jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, tooltip

I have the following code for displaying a validation error in a tooltip:

```
<form name="NATIPRangeForm">
    <div class="input-group">
        <strong class="ip-value-title">Base Address:</strong>
        <input class="ip-input" type="number" id="ip_seg_1" name="ip" ng-model="nat.ip.seg1" min="0" max="255" required>.
        <input class="ip-input" type="number" id="ip_seg_2" name="ip" ng-model="nat.ip.seg2" min="0" max="255" required>.
        <input class="ip-input" type="number" id="ip_seg_3" name="ip" ng-model="nat.ip.seg3" min="0" max="255" required>.
        <input class="ip-input" type="number" id="ip_seg_4" name="ip" ng-model="nat.ip.seg4" min="0" max="255" required>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $("#NATIPRangeForm").validate({

        rules: {
            ip: {
                required: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 255,
                number: true
            }
        },

        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            $.each(this.successList, function (index, value) {
                return $(value).popover("hide");
            });
            return $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {
                var _popover;
                console.log(value.message);
                _popover = $(value.element).popover({
                    trigger: "manual",
                    placement: "bottom",
                    content: value.message,
                    template: "<div class=\"popover\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div>"
                });
                _popover.data("bs.popover").options.content = value.message;
                return $(value.element).popover("show");
            });
        }
    });

    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>
```

This works great but there is one issue:

[image: image of overlapping dialogs]

Is there an easy of only displaying one error popup at a time?

Comment: What plugin are you using for constructing the tooltips?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `showErrors` for tooltips because this callback function is typically used for generating a list of all messages, like for a summary at the top of the form.  [*"Gets the map of errors as the first argument and an array of errors as the second."*](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors)  Using `showErrors` is the primary cause of your reported problem.  You want the errors one a time, not all at once.

You did explain anything about how you're constructing the tooltips, but you'll need to integrate your tooltips plugin with jQuery Validate by using its `errorPlacement` and `success` callback functions; which will put the single *pending* error message inside a single tooltip.  This integration also depends on the available options of your tooltips plugin... like can you dynamically change the text inside a tooltip?  Can you dynamically/programmatically show/hide them, etc?

Something more like this...

```
$("#NATIPRangeForm").validate({
    rules: {
        ip: {
            required: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 255,
            number: true
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        // put text of error into tooltip with $(error).text()
        // show tooltip
    },
    success: function (label, element) {
        // hide the tooltip
    },
    // any other options
});
```

[I'm using the ToolTipster jQuery plugin like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235).

**Demo using ToolTipster plugin:  http://jsfiddle.net/2DUX2/3/**