# jQuery validation showErrors blocks highlight/unhighlight

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

It appears to me that the jquery-validation showErrors blocks the action of highlight and unhighlight.

In html I have a required form-group:

```
        <form id="ValidationForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="form-group required">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="Letters">Letters</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 controls">
                                <input class="form-control input-md" id="Letters" name="Letters" type="text" placeholder="Letters" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input id="btnSave" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="btnSave">
                        </div></form>
```

In javascript I have rules for the validator defined:

```
var rules = {
    rules: {
        "Letters": { required: true }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $('#btnSave').prop("disabled", true);
        form.submit();
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $.each(this.successList, function(index, value) {
            return $(value).popover("hide");
        });
        return $.each(errorList, function(index, value) {
            var _popover;
            _popover = $(value.element).popover({
                trigger: "manual",
                placement: "auto",
                content: value.message,
                template: "<div class=\"popover\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div>"
            });
            _popover.data("bs.popover").options.content = value.message;
            return $(value.element).popover("show");
        });
    }
};
$("#ValidationForm").validate(rules);
```

If I remove the showErrors and press the submit button the form-group has the "has-errors" class added and the input border is displayed as red. When showErrors is added, this highlight functionality disappears. Any ideas why?

Comment: Please be aware of your tag usage.  The jQuery Validate plugin uses the [tag:jquery-validate] tag, not [tag:jquery-validation-engine], an entirely different plugin.  Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It appears to me that the jquery-validation showErrors blocks the action of highlight and unhighlight.

I'm not entirely sure what final effect you're trying to achieve since you never explained it.  However, the `highlight` and `unhighlight` options are only used for controlling what happens when a message is supposed to appear next to an input.  Whereas the [`showErrors` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) is used for creating a centrally locate summary of all errors someplace on the page.  I don't know how or why you'd want to use the two together, and I'm not entirely certain how one option would "block" the other.

After looking at the code within your `showErrors` function, it appears that you're trying to create a popup effect for each message.  In that case, `showErrors` is not the correct choice for this purpose.

You'd want to use the [`errorPlacement`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) and [`success`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success) options for tooltips or popups.  These options operate on each input one at a time as each error occurs, whereas `showErrors` will fire whenever there are errors anywhere on the form.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    // put text of error into tooltip with $(error).text()
    // show tooltip
},
success: function (label, element) {
    // hide the tooltip
},
```

Refer to my answer below, which discusses this in more detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241902/594235