# I need to validate a postcode input between 3030 and 3340

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am making a form for customers to quickly see if the business services their area. I need the input to validate the input postcode from 3030 to 3340.

If it is true then a pop-up dialog box will appear with confirmation of service and contact triggers. If false then a dialog appears informing the customer that their area is not currently serviced by the business.

I know I haven't created the .poscode-valid or .postcode-invalid yet. I also don't want the selection arrows so a fix that removes them would be good. Thanks for any help.

```js
// // ********************************************************************************
// // This script checks to see if the postcode matched the excepted field and returns
// // a dialog box accordingly 
// // ********************************************************************************
// this script need to evaluate the input against input numbers >=3030 && <=3340.
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.postcode_form').validate({
        rules: {
          range: [3030, 3340]
        }
        if (range = true) {
          $('.postcode_form').addClass('.postcode_valid')
        } else {
          $('.postcode_form').addClass('.postcode_invalid')
        }
      });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#service_area {
  background: #245353;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
.service_area_container {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.area h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}
.area h5 {
  margin: 0 2em 2em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.0385em;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.area_input {
  width: 184px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
input.your_postcode {
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0 -6px 0 0;
  padding: 14px 17px 12px 17px;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.0585em;
  z-index: 1;
}
.area_input .submit {
  padding: 14px 17px 12px 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.0356em;
  font-weight: 100;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="service_area" class="scrolling-bg bg-3">
  <div class="service_area_container area">
    <h1>Where's the job?</h1>

    <h5>Enter your <span class="high_light">postcode</span> below to see if we <span class="high_light">service</span> the <span class="high_light">area</span></h5>

    <div class="area_input">
      <form class="postcode_form">
        <input type="number" id="your_postcode" class="your_postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode">
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
        <div class="loading"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- .area_input -->
  </div>
  <!-- .service_area_container -->
</section>
<!-- #service_area -->
```

You can see the code I have thus far here: http://jsfiddle.net/paralellos/6fr1chqo/

Comment: You don't appear to state exactly what your current _problem_ is (other than the arrows which is a side issue). What's actually _wrong_ with what you currently have? In other words, what do you want us to do?

Comment: You can't put Javascript statements insid an object literal. What is that `if (range = true)` stuff supposed to do? Also, remember to use `==` for comparisons, `=` is for assigments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paralellos/6fr1chqo/)...

1. It was missing jQuery itself.
2. It was missing the jQuery Validate plugin.
3. Inside the `rules` option, you forgot to declare the `name` of the field.

   ```
   rules: {
       postcode: { // <- NAME of the input
           range: [3030, 3340]
       }
   }
   ```
4. You forgot to properly close the DOM ready event handler function with a `});`
5. You broke the plugin by putting an `if` statement within the `.validate()` method.  [The `.validate()` method only accepts an object literal, this is comprised of a comma separated list of `key: value` pairs enclosed by braces, as defined by the plugin's author](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/), nothing else.
6. I added a `required: true` to make the field mandatory.
7. Change `type="number"` to `type="text"` to remove the up/down arrows on your `input` element.  The user will not be allowed to enter non-numeric characters because the `range` rule is looking for numbers and triggers an error otherwise.

**Your fixed DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6fr1chqo/3/**

---

> If it is true then a pop-up dialog box will appear with confirmation of service and contact triggers. If false then a dialog appears informing the customer that their area is not currently serviced by the business.

The jQuery Validate plugin has nothing to do with pop-up messages or dialog boxes.  This plugin merely inserts the text of the error message immediately after each input element.  Any styling or integration of pop-ups is up to you.  However, I recommend a jQuery plugin for pop-ups as it's not as simple as it may seem.

If you want a message to appear when there is *not* an error and the field passes validation, then you must use the `success` callback function.

```
success: function(label) {
    label.addClass("valid").text("Area Serviced")
},
```

To say "Area NOT serviced" instead of the generic message when the field is not valid, use the `messages` option...

```
messages: {
    postcode: {
        required: "enter a Postcode",
        range: "Area NOT serviced"
    }
},
```

**Updated DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6fr1chqo/4/**

[A generic example that integrates the ToolTipster plugin with jQuery Validate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741688/how-to-display-messages-from-jquery-validate-plugin-inside-of-tooltipster-toolti)

Comment: I don't know why but when I add your code to my main.js file and then enter a postcode, true or false, and press enter or the Submit button the page just returned to the top and no message is outputted

Comment: @Paralellos, there is no way for me to know what you've done wrong.  Everything posted here is working in the jsFiddle.

Comment: I just can't get this to work! are there any common problems you can recommend I look for? At the moment I press the submit button and nothing happens. Nothing happens when typing like it does on your fiddle and if I press enter I'm taken to the top of the mage where the address has '?postcode=' attached to the end.

Comment: @Paralellos, given how many errors were in your original code, I could not even begin to guess what is wrong now.  Make sure you've properly included the plugin after jQuery, check your browser console for errors, and double check every line of code to make sure you're not making the same syntax mistakes again or any new ones.

Comment: I have it working now!! :) I think the problem was a conflict with some other js I was using elsewhere, which I have now removed. Thanks for all your help.  There are just a few things I would like to fix and if you think you can help that would be cool. It all works when I press submit, which is now a button. But if I just press enter it still snaps to top of screen? would this be a keyup issue? also how can I make the label disappear on scroll or when the mouse leaves the .service_area_container? Again thank you for your help to this point.

Comment: @Paralellos, snapping to the top of the screen makes no sense to me.  If the plugin is installed and working properly, there is nothing that would cause what you describe.  Making labels disappear by actions that are not part of the plugin would require that you write custom event handler functions.  However, when you start writing functions that take over things like that, you could potentially break the plugin.... see first half of this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give *one* possibility for the "removal of the arrows" bit, though it's a bit of a kludge.

If you set the input type to be `text` rather than `number`, the arrows will disappear.

The kludgy bit is that you'll now have to do *extra* validation to ensure the entered data is fully numeric, something like:

```
rules: {
    postcode: {
        number: true,
        range: [3030, 3340]
    }
}
```

Comment: The `number` rule is superfluous and redundant, because the `range` rule can only accept numbers and triggers errors on any non-numeric characters.

Comment: @paxdiablo, to remove the number I found out you can use the css `input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 margin: 0;
}`