# jquery validation error messages using bootstrap does't work properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have developed following code to display tool tip like error messages on validating form. Only after validate this form should be able to view next form.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn1").click(function(){

            $("#form1").validate({

                rules: {
                    firstname: {
                        required: true,

                    },
                    lastname: {
                        required: true,

                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,

                    }

                },
                tooltip_options: {
               firstname: { 
                  placement: 'right' 
                  },
                  lastname: { 
                  placement: 'right' 
                  },
                  email: { 
                  placement: 'right' 
                  }
                }
            });

        if ($("#form1").valid() == true){
                document.getElementById('form2_container').style.display = "block";
                   document.getElementById('form2_container').scrollIntoView();


            }   

        });
        // JavaScript Document
    });
    </script>
```

But next form suddenly displayed and it disappears. What would be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the issue?

You've probably broken the plugin with invalid options.  Although you have not shown your HTML, so there might be other issues with your markup.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#btn1").click(function(){

            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    lastname: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                    }
                },
                tooltip_options: { // <- no such option for this plugin
                firstname: { 
                  placement: 'right' 
                  },
                  lastname: { 
                  placement: 'right' 
                  },
                  email: { 
                  placement: 'right' 
                  }
                }
            });  // <- close '.validate()'

            if ($("#form1").valid() == true){
                document.getElementById('form2_container').style.display = "block";
                   document.getElementById('form2_container').scrollIntoView()
            }   

        }); // <- close click handler

    }); // <- close DOM ready handler
</script>
```

1. You can only put [an object literal inside the `.validate()` method that is constructed as per the plugin's author](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).  You cannot use non-existant options inside `.validate()`.  In other words, `tooltip_options` is not a valid option for the jQuery Validate plugin.
2. You cannot put `.validate()` inside of a `click` handler.  The `.validate()` method is only used for ***initializing*** the plugin on your form and therefore only belongs inside of a DOM ready event handler.  Once initialized, it *automatically* captures the click of the `submit` button.

**I suggest that you review [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and [the SO Tag Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for proper construction, helpful tips and example code.**

Integrating tool-tips into this plugin is [not as simple as you may think](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14741688/594235).

---

BTW:

```
if ($("#form1").valid() == true){....
```

would be *identical* to...

```
if ($("#form1").valid()){....
```

Comment: I use another plugin along with jquery  https://github.com/Thrilleratplay/jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip

Comment: I think somehow triggering form reset. Any ways to stop resetting form explicitly?

Comment: ok got it. Its a html error. Need to change input type to button since this is a multiple step form. Thanks