# Bootstrap Popovers will not show properly if offscreen on a mobile device

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, bootstrap-popover

As the title says, the popovers will not show properly if off screen. This seems like it makes sense, but the arrow for the popover still shows up. I need the popover to be visible on the page even if it is off screen.

I am using the popovers to serve as validation notices on my form. I am using jquery validate, the plugin.

This is the image of what happens. [image: Screenshot of issue]

Here is the code for the validation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form1").validate({
            onsubmit: false,
            rules: {
                ctl00$MainContent$txtEventName: { required: true },
                ctl00$MainContent$txtEventDate: { required: true, date: true },
                ctl00$MainContent$txtEventGuests: { required: true, number: true },
                ctl00$MainContent$txtZip: { required: true, number: true, minlength: 5 },
                ctl00$MainContent$txtEmail: { required: true, email: true },
                ctl00$MainContent$txtPwd: { required: true },
                ctl00$MainContent$txtConfirmPwd: { equalTo: "#MainContent_txtPwd" }
            },
            messages: {
                ctl00$MainContent$txtEventName: "Please enter the event name",
                ctl00$MainContent$txtEventDate: "Please enter a date that is not before today",
                ctl00$MainContent$txtEventGuests: "Please enter the amount of guests attending the event",
                ctl00$MainContent$txtZip: "Please enter a valid zipcode",
                ctl00$MainContent$txtEmail: "Please enter a valid email address",
                ctl00$MainContent$txtConfirmPwd: "Your passwords must match"
            },
            showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
                //$.each(this.successList, function(index, value) {
                //    return $(value).popover("hide");
                //});
                return $.each(errorList, function(index, value) {
                    var _popover;
                    _popover = $(value.element).popover({
                        placement: "right",
                        content: value.message,
                        template: "<div class=\"popover\" style='width: 195px;'><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"></div></div></div>"
                    });
                    return $(value.element).popover("show");
                });
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                return false; // for debug
            }
        });
    });
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your methodology is slightly flawed.  `showErrors` is used for composing a list of error messages for the whole form; it's not typically used to handle each message as it happens.  For tooltips, you'll need to deal with each message as it occurs, not all of them at once.

For showing/hiding tooltips for your errors, you'll need to use the `errorPlacement` and `success` callback functions instead.

Adjust as needed for Bootstrap popovers...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
          // rules and options here,
          errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
              // construct tooltip with message as per plugin method
              // show tooltip
          },
          success: function (label, element) {
              // hide tooltip as per plugin method
          }
    });

});
```

**Reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235**

**Documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate**

---

Alternatively, here is a plugin that is supposed to automatically integrate jQuery Validate with Bootstrap Popovers, however, I have never used it myself.

https://github.com/mingliangfeng/jquery.validate.bootstrap.popover