# trying to add a custom validation to jquery validator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

i am trying to add a custom validation field to the validator firld using the addClassRules but it is not working..

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("checkrequired", {
      rules: {
        required: true
      },
      tooltip_options: {
        '_all_': {
            placement: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    });
```

i need to add a placeholder as i want to show the error in the tooltip.

The whole idea is that i want to use this class or `addmethod` as you suggested for multiple fields which are getting generated from the database, so a message will be common, the field is required.

and all those error message will be appearing in the `tooltip`, all i want to either use the `addClassRules` or `addMethod` to make it work

Comment: *"all i want to either use the `addClassRules` or `addMethod` to make it work"* ~ **you can't**

Answer (score 0):

> i am trying to add a custom validation field to the validator firld using the `addClassRules`

That's just not possible...

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("checkrequired", {
    rules: {
        required: true
    },
    tooltip_options: {  // <- totally invalid option
        '_all_': {
            placement: 'bottom'
        }
    }
});
```

[The `addClassRules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/) is simply meant for making compound rules and assigning the new compound rule to a `class` name.

> ***Description***: Add a compound class method – useful to refactor common combinations of rules into a single class.

**You can only put existing rules/methods into the `addClassRules()` method, not the object literal from an entirely different plugin.**

If you're trying to create a new validation rule from scratch, you'd use [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

---

> "i need to add a placeholder as i want to show the error in placeholder"

You've really not explained this very well at all, but I don't think this has anything to do with creating a new validation rule.

[There are various options and functions you can use to over-ride the default behavior](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).  Please improve your question so we can help you.

If you're trying to integrate a tooltip plugin with jQuery Validate, that is much more involved.  See this for an example using the ToolTipster plugin.

[How to display messages from jQuery Validate plugin inside of Tooltipster tooltips?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14741688/594235)

However, be aware that every tooltip plugin is going to have a slightly different solution depending on its capabilities.

---

> *"all i want to either use the `addClassRules` or `addMethod` to make it work"*

**You can't.**

Those two methods are specific to creating new methods (validation rules), they have nothing to do with the behavior of message placement.  Again, review [the available configuration options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).