# jQuery Validation required not clearing tooltipster error message when based on a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, tooltipster

This seemed like something simple, but I am stumped. I have a form and want a field to be required if the value of another field is greater than zero. While the validation actually works and allows me to submit, the error tooltip doesn't clear when I change the value back to zero.

In the fiddle, if the Misc amount is greater than 0, i want the comments to be required, otherwise not required. As I said, the validation works, but the validation message doesn't get cleared.

```js
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          //Initialize the tooltips
          jQuery('.tooltip').tooltipster({
            contentAsHTML: true
          });
          jQuery('#frmForm :input').each(function() {
            var tipelement = getTipContainer(this);

            jQuery(tipelement).tooltipster({
              trigger: 'custom',
              onlyOne: false,
              position: 'right',
              multiple: true,
              autoClose: true
            });

          });
          jQuery("#frmForm").validate({
            ignore: [],
            rules: {
              MISCComments: {
                required: function(element) {
                  return jQuery("#MISCAmount").val() > 0;
                }
              }
            },
            messages: {
              MISCComments: "Explain what this payment is for."
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
              var $element = jQuery(element),
                tipelement = element,
                errtxt = jQuery(error).text(),
                last_error = '';

              tipelement = getTipContainer(element);

              last_error = jQuery(tipelement).data('last_error');
              jQuery(tipelement).data('last_error', errtxt);
              if (errtxt !== '' && errtxt != last_error) {
                jQuery(tipelement).tooltipster('content', errtxt);
                jQuery(tipelement).tooltipster('show');
              }
            },
            success: function(label, element) {
              var tipelement = getTipContainer(element);
              jQuery(tipelement).tooltipster('hide');
            }
          });

          //this function selects a container for 'group' elements like
          //check box /radio groups
          function getTipContainer(element) {
            var tipelement = element;
            if (jQuery(element).is(":checkbox") || jQuery(element).is(":radio")) {
              tipelement = jQuery(element).parents('.container').get(0);
            }
            return tipelement;
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/css/tooltipster.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form name="frmForm" id="frmForm" method="post">

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      CE Vendor Fees
      <input type="hidden" name="CE_VENDORS" id="CE_VENDORS" value="CE_VENDORS">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input id="CE_VENDORSInvoiceNumber" name="CE_VENDORSInvoiceNumber" type="text" placeholder="Invoice #" class="form-control input-md" style="20px;" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input id="CE_VENDORSAmount" name="CE_VENDORSAmount" type="text" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control input-md Amounts" value="2.00" style="text-align: right;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <input id="CE_VENDORSComments" name="CE_VENDORSComments" type="text" placeholder="Comments" class="form-control input-md" value="">
      <label for="CE_VENDORSComments" class="error"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Miscellaneous
      <input type="hidden" name="MISC" id="MISC" value="MISC">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input id="MISCInvoiceNumber" name="MISCInvoiceNumber" type="text" placeholder="Invoice #" class="form-control input-md" style="20px;" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input id="MISCAmount" name="MISCAmount" type="text" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control input-md Amounts" value="1.00" style="text-align: right;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <input id="MISCComments" name="MISCComments" type="text" placeholder="Comments" class="form-control input-md" value="">

    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="button-tooltip" title="Submit details">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/timgill/sk074zwv/)

Comment: I reworked my answer using your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dynamically changing the rule, you'll need to programmatically force validation of this field when the value of the dependent field is edited.

```
jQuery('[name="MISCAmount"]').on('blur keyup', function() {
    jQuery('[name="MISCComments"]').valid();  // force validation
});
```

Also...

The `success` function will not re-fire on an "optional" field when this field is blanked out or the rules are changed.  This is the root issue.   Your field is dynamically changed from `required` into "optional" and there is no way to force the `success` function to re-fire for this case.

The solution is to use the `unhighlight` function instead of `success`, which fires every single time a field is evaluated for validity.  The following code attaches the `show` and `hide` methods to these default functions.

```
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass).tooltipster('hide');
},
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass).tooltipster('show');
},
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/sk074zwv/9/](https://jsfiddle.net/sk074zwv/9/)**

[Quoting myself from this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14741689/594235):

> *"I also replaced the `success` callback with `unhighlight`. On "optional" fields, the error message was never removed when the field was subsequently blanked out... this is because the `success` function does not fire under these circumstances."*

---

I also recommend that you upgrade to ToolTipster version 4 and rework your code for such.  Version 4 contains some new/improved methods such as `open` and `close`, which makes a little more sense for toggling tooltips, and works very well with `highlight` and `unhighlight`.